# Transmitting raw data using cURL

Tags: curl

I need to transmit raw data to a server, which is NO http-Server. I.e. it does not understand POST, PUT or similar commands. It just listens on a port waiting for incoming data, processes them and sends data back. BTW: the server is listening on a non-standard port, i.e. 3500.

Whatever options I tried in cURL, I can't transmit data correctly. cURL always sends at least a "POST" or a "PUT" before the actual data is sent. The server then responds to me with "…invalid data…".

Options I've tried: --data-raw, --data-binary, --upload-file, --raw, just to name a few.

Is there a chance to suppress the transmission of "POST" or "PUT" before cURL sends the data?

Comment: why do you want to use curl for this - why not just pipe data forward?

Comment: curl (command-line tool) doesn't support arbitrary network protocols, just some [specific ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL#cURL). Maybe [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @PeterWolf consider making that an answer

Comment: @PeterWolf: yes, netcat seems to do the job, I must investigate further how to integrate this into our software - for macOS and Win. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use the `telnet` protocol option for curl to accomplish what you want.

Put the raw data you want to transmit in a file (or pipe from stdin) and execute curl along these lines:

```
cat commands.txt | curl telnet://server:3500
```

Using the telnet protocol handler for curl, it will connect and transmit the data it receives and then read the response.

Note: If the server doesn't terminate the connection after it sends data in response to your commands, curl will likely keep the connection open waiting for more data.  If this is the case, you may want to try `nc` (netcat), or write a small, simple program that can do bi-directional communication.

Comment: sorry but telnet is a protocol on top of TCP, OP did not say that his server use the telnet protocol. - sounds like a job for netcat.

Comment: @drew010: I tried your suggestion but somehow transmission from the server stopped after 8.192 bytes :-( Netcat works fine, just investigating further - see my comments above. Thanks anyway!

Comment: sigh @hanshenrik, they didn't say telnet but using curl with `telnet://` just opens a connection and sends whatever you tell it. Works for most all tcp based socket servers where you want to send and then receive. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @drew010 no, it doesn't. if you try to send binary data over telnet:// with curl, curl may corrupt the data. you can easily verify this yourself with a little test: first do `dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1 iflag=fullblock | md5sum` - what checksum do you get? i get `f1c9645dbc14efddc7d8a322685f26eb`  - then open a little netcat server, `nc -l 9999 | md5sum`, then run the command `dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=1 iflag=fullblock | curl telnet://127.0.0.1:9999`, what checksum do you get? i get `c04ba4470a4374019c008c5f724d8e58` - the 10 megabytes of nulls became corrupted with curl+telnet://

Comment: (prior to making that test, i wasn't 100% certain myself, but testing shows that your telnet:// approach doesn't work properly with binary data, like nulls. would be a cool hack if that actually worked tho. wonder if someone ever asked Daniel Stenberg to implement a `tcp://` protocol )

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering too that cURL apparently doesn't support simple TCP socket communication ;-) That's why I've been asking the gurus here… I'll give it a try on the cURL forum…

Comment: And yes, the data is encrypted, so everything is possible - from 0x00 to 0xFF

Comment: @hanshenrik Good call. Sorry for that reaction earlier. I had mostly assumed ascii data and it worked well with that, but didn't test with binary. From looking at the curl source, there aren't really any options to get it to pass everything through untouched or read data back as-is.

Comment: if you can alter the code on the receiving end, you could base64 encode the data, then decode it on the opposite side.  curl also supports ftp, scp, etc.

Comment: note: I've found using this method that some payloads consistently have extra trailing FF bytes received. and netcat on the same machine did add the trailing bytes. Must be something to do with curl or the telnet protocol.

Answer (score 1):

i think this question is suitable for www.superuser.com rather than stackoverflow, and have voted to close it, but here goes:

this isn't a job for curl, it's a job for [Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). use cat to read the file, and netcat to send the file and get the response, eg

```
cat file.ext | nc server.com 3500
```

(there are several netcat implementations, like the original `*Hobbit*`'s netcat, and GNU netcat, and *BSD netcat, i believe some netcat implementations need the syntax `nc -p 3500 server.com` instead, but if you're using GNU netcat, or Cygwin's netcat, or MacOS's netcat, the above syntax should work fine. for the record, many Linux systems ship with GNU netcat)

if you're on Windows, which doesn't ship with cat/netcat, you can install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com) which has both. MacOS and most Linux distros ship with netcat & cat by default.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use cURL is that we can call it as a plugin from our business software - on both platforms (macOS and Win). For netcat we don't have an appropriate implementation as for cURL.

Comment: BTW: netcat DOES the job - just tested on macOS 10.14. I'm investigating further. Thank you!

Comment: @JörgEyring well most programming languages have support for raw tcp sockets, which is what you need.. if it's written in PHP, check [fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), if it's written in C++ check [boost::ip::tcp::socket](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html), if it's written in Pythion check [Socket()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and so on~